# Getting inputs of multiple fields in a javascript function and adding the values of each field

Tags: javascript, html

I made this dummy javascript function that gets multiple fields and adding the values of each field.

here is the code:

```
function calculate(){
var a;
var debNo = parseInt("<%=deb%>");
var debTotal = 0.0;
for(a = 0; a < debNo; a++){
    debTotal = debTotal + parseDouble(document.getElementById("debAmt"+a).value);
}

document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=(debTotal);
}
</script>
```

I have a problem in the `document.getElementById("debAmt"+a).value` part. It seems that it does not add the values inside the input fields. I hope you guys can help me in my dilemma. Thank you for answering!

Comment: can you print (or share) the value of debNo after third line? Also share the markup value. Any errors on the console?

Comment: use parseFloat instead of parseDouble

Comment: Changed it to parseFloat and it worked! Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think parseDouble is main issue in this code please try parseFloat()

```
function calculate(){
var a;
var debNo = parseInt("<%=deb%>");
var debTotal = 0.0;
for(a = 0; a < debNo; a++){
    debTotal = debTotal + parseFloat(document.getElementById("debAmt"+a).value);
}

document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=(debTotal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the problem it is working fine here with me. Just use parseFloat instead of parseDouble

```
<body >    
<input type="hidden" id="debAmt1" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" id="debAmt2" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" id="debAmt3" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" id="debAmt4" value="80"/>
<input type="hidden" id="debAmt5" value="1"/>   
</body>
<script> 
 calculate();
    function calculate(){
    var a;
    var debTotal = 0.0;
    for(a = 1; a < 6; a++){
        debTotal = debTotal + parseFloat(document.getElementById("debAmt"+a).value);
    }
    alert(debTotal);
    }
</script>
```